# In Trigger getting error as error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a trigger which was working earlier perfectly. But later on, as required I added some more lines into that which is below

```
declare @imkey numeric(10,0);declare @xmkey numeric(10,0); declare @xsrno numeric(10,0)
            select  @xmkey=max([Mkey])+1, @xsrno=max([Entry_Sr_No])+1 
            from erp190516.[dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl] where Ref_Mkey=@imkey;
            select @imkey=i.Inward_ref_key from inserted i 

            insert into erp190516.[dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl]
            SELECT  @xmkey,@xsrno,[N_UserMkey],'1' [N_Department], 'F' [CStatus_Flag]
            ,'Requester' [Remarks],'1' [CUser_ID],getdate() [U_Datetime],
            ,'N' [NStatus_Flag], 'N' [Delete_Flag]
            ,'1'[CDept_Id],[Ref_Mkey],[No_Of_Days],[Approved_Amount],[Chq_No],[Chq_dated]
            ,[Chq_Bank],[Chq_Amount],[Vendor_MKey],[Vendor_Comp_Mkey]
            ,[Project_Mkey],[Program_mkey],[Payment_MKey],[Due_Date],[Updated_Remarks]
            ,[Updated_Bill_no],[Updated_Bill_Date],[Updated_Bill_Amt]
            ,[Party_Name],[Acc_mkey],[TotalDeductions],[Broker_Mkey],[Customer_Mkey]
            ,[Payable_Amt],[Balance_Amt],[Receipt_No],[Po_No],[Bill_No]
            ,[Disp_through],[Disp_Through_Name],[Site_Id]
        FROM erp190516.[dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl] where Ref_Mkey=@imkey
```

It eexcuted perfectly, but while inserting the data into the table I got error as

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

**Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl](
            [Mkey] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
            [Entry_Sr_No] [numeric](4, 0) NOT NULL,
            [N_UserMkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [N_Department] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [CStatus_Flag] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
            [Remarks] [varchar](500) NULL,
            [CUser_ID] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
            [U_Datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
            [NStatus_Flag] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
            [Delete_Flag] [char](1) NULL,
            [CDept_Id] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
            [Ref_Mkey] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
            [No_Of_Days] [int] NULL,
            [Approved_Amount] [float] NULL,
            [Chq_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Chq_dated] [datetime] NULL,
            [Chq_Bank] [varchar](40) NULL,
            [Chq_Amount] [float] NULL,
            [Vendor_MKey] [int] NULL,
            [Vendor_Comp_Mkey] [int] NULL,
            [Project_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [Program_mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [Payment_MKey] [int] NULL,
            [Due_Date] [datetime] NULL,
            [Updated_Remarks] [varchar](500) NULL,
            [Updated_Bill_no] [varchar](27) NULL,
            [Updated_Bill_Date] [datetime] NULL,
            [Updated_Bill_Amt] [float] NULL,
            [Party_Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
            [Acc_mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [TotalDeductions] [float] NULL,
            [Broker_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [Customer_Mkey] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
            [Payable_Amt] [float] NULL,
            [Balance_Amt] [float] NULL,
            [Receipt_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Po_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Bill_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Oracle_doc_no] [varchar](100) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Mkey] ASC,
            [Entry_Sr_No] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO

        SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl_U_Datetime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [U_Datetime]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inward_Doc_Tracking_Trl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Inward_Do__Delet__47FED732]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Delete_Flag]
        GO
```

Comment: After [U_Datetime], there are 2 commas

Comment: Could you share the table's definition?

Comment: May not relate to your current problems (which seems like a simple data type mismatch that you can't expect *us* to resolve without knowing your table definitions) but your trigger seems to have two errors - first, your first select seems to use `@imkey` before it's ever set to a value, and second, the second select assumes that `inserted` contains exactly *one* row. That is **not** a safe assumption. Triggers should be written to work against an `inserted` table that can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows.

Comment: @Mureinik: added the definition in the question

Comment: Go through your columns in the table vs the columns in your trigger, because when it cannot convert - you have mismatch of datatypes

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I have just posted a section of the trigger which is causing the issue. Not posted all the code

Comment: No, you may not have posted all of the code, but `select @imkey=i.Inward_ref_key from inserted i` is categorically *wrong*, since as I say, `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows. Also, if you're not posting all of the code, but you're still posting *multiple* statements, how have you isolated the problem down to *these* statements but not been able to isolate it to a *single* statement?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: because As I said in my question, the trigger was working earlier. After adding this statement by saving issue started.

Comment: It can (have) run, but if you have multiple rows in your trigger; it might not actually _work_ as intended because of the issue @Damien_The_Unbeliever points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting character values in [NStatus_Flag] and [CStatus_Flag] , Just change their data type in table or insert data with numeric value into them.

Answer (score 1):

Well - one obvious error is that you have `[CStatus_Flag] [numeric](8, 0)` but select `'F' [CStatus_Flag]`.

Also just for clarity sake, but you shouldn't write `'1'` for selection of numeric fields either, when `1` can do it without conversions.

Comment: I changed it to `0` from `F`. but I still get error while saving

Comment: There are likely more of the same error, when you have datatype mismatchs like this. You need to go through your select and be sure it selects the same datatype as you the table you want to insert into because obviously it does not.

Comment: There were 2 places where I need to make changes, I did that and it worked